# How to disable LSP-bridge's path-completion on certain directories?

Tags: lsp, path

**Goal**:

- Disable [LSP-Bridge](https://github.com/manateelazycat/lsp-bridge)'s path-completion on `/bin/` directory.
- But let it be work on other directories. (I really like it)

**Why**:
When I edit some small shell scripts, path-completion feature hangs more than 5-10 seconds on `/bin` directory. Which frustrates me to wait very long. I'm assuming this is because number of items in the `/bin` directory (which is ~5000 in my case).

[image]

**What I've tried:**
Basically none. My experience it not enough at the time. I haven't even find which elisp function is doing the path-completion feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/manateelazycat/lsp-bridge/commit/eb50e4ca8e7fa59861b49393605bd65e55306d2b

Has fixed this, please update.

Comment: Damn, @ManateeLazyCat, you yourself work blazingly as fast as your lsp-bridge. Really appreciate it. I'm a fan of your project.

Comment: I'm not sure what is happening, When I checkout this commit `eb50e4c`, the popup-menu for path-completion doesn't show up. (while on  previous commit `5716cce`, path-completion pops up).

Comment: you need emacs -Q for compare test. please send an issue if still have problem

Comment: It works just fine. Thank you,